# Replace a line in the file using sed, line has a moving portion in the center of it

Tags: regex, sed

There is a moving portion in the line.

`sed` needs to search for a line that might have anything in the center of it.

In other words we are looking to find this line by telling `sed` that it starts with

```
 aaa
```

and ends with

```
 ccc
```

the center could be anything.

Let's say we have a file called `a.txt`, and this is what is in it.

```
 a
 b
 aaa111ccc
```

`sed` needs to find the line that looks like..

```
 aaa(.*)ccc
```

And then replace it with

```
 "_TEST_"
```

The output should be `aaa_TEST_bbb`

Comment: Now it is a good question! So the desired output would be `"_TEST_"` instead of `aaa111ccc`?

Comment: @fedorqui, the output would be `aaa_TEST_bbb`

Comment: Can there be multiple lines between `aaa` and `ccc` ?

Comment: Which means `aaa` and `ccc` can appear in different lines?

Comment: @anubhava, no, no new lines. aaa*ccc on the same line.

Comment: Hmm in that case @Tripleee's answer should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: @anubhava, so far, it seems to be emptying the whole file, still trying to find out if `.*` is correct in his code, also i think there was a need for a /g at the end of the first portion.

Comment: Yes you can use an improved one: `sed 's/^\(aaa\).*\(ccc\)$/\1_TEST_\2/g'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which part do you need help with?

```
sed 's/^aaa.*bbb$/aaa_TEST_bbb/' file >newfile
```

If you want to edit the file in place, remove the redirection and add a suitable `-i` option (provided your `sed` supports it).